# Global.Asax not updating after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, global-asax

I made some changes in the Global.Asax file to include CORS, but after publishing I noticed the Global.Asax file in the browser is 6 months old, how I force VS to update it to the latest version?

Comment: "Global.Asax file in the browser" Woah! Stop. That file should never be accessible by the browser. Did you modify your configuration to allow that?

Comment: @mason sorry, I meant the server, since I was getting the same errors I went to check the server